# Communication methodology to connect Desktop to Android with out internet connection

Tags: android

i wanted to communication between Desktop to Android device with out internet connection.

Kindly any one suggest me what the possible and best methodology to do so.

As per my knowledge please find below :
1) Wifi
2) Blutooth
3) Socket Programming

but i dont know which is the best methodolog.

Thanks and regards,
Dhaval